# How to delete orphans in OneToOne relation in Hibernate when parent keeps preserved?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

I have a parent with the following field...

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "rcp_pf_id_photodata")
private PersistableFile photoData;
```

Persistable file looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTABLE_FILE")
public class PersistableFile
{
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize=1, initialValue=1, sequenceName="persistablefile_pf_id_seq", name="persistablefile_pf_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="persistablefile_pf_id_seq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pf_id")
    private Long pfId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pf_filename")
    private String filename;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pf_content")
    private byte[] content;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pf_filetype")
    private String filetype;

        //more code
}
```

When the parent will be deleted, then the persistable file (child) will be deleted as well. This is ok. But when the parent keeps preserved, and I set `setPhotoData(null);` then the child will not be deleted. Obviously Hibernate is not smart enough to recognize that an old relation was deleted. If I do `setPhotoData(null)` nothing happens to the child and after updating the parent entity, the child will remain in database forever.

This is a @OneToOne relationship, so I can't do `clear()` on it. I doubt that setting all fields of the child to null would be the proper way to delete the orphan (which is not possible, due to all the not null fields), but what is the right way to do that?

Comment: I don't think setting a relation to null will trigger a cascade operation. You probably need to delete the `PersistableFile` entity yourself.

Comment: @K.Nicholas It works with EAGER, see my answer. That's why I think it's a bug.

Comment: Perhaps so, or since you have not fetched it there is nothing to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it works with `FetchType.EAGER`. Looks like a bug to me.